# Can Grunt load remote files over HTTP directly from the `src` value in files object/array or globs?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, asset-pipeline, build-process, frontend

You can use `grunt-http` or `grunt-curl` etc. to download a remote file to a temporary location on disk and then read it. However it would be cleaner if that step could be skipped and we could use the Grunt files objects/arrays/globbing to download the file directly. Something like:

```js
grunt.initConfig({
  uglify: {
    test: {
      files: [
        { src: 'http://example.com/cool-file.js', dest: 'build/cool-file.min.js' }
      ],
    },
});
```

(In my particular case I need my build process to work off of HTML files generated by a local Python Tornado web server with a lot of templating logic that I can't replicate elsewhere.)

I've tried searching for a plugin that would streamline this but no dice. Any options or patterns for doing this other than downloading the files in a separate task?

Answer (score 0):

I first thought I will say

> Are you an ambitious developper?
>
> First try! Then ask.

But seem you have already try, then... instead of reporting thi pseudo-issue here, post it to their github account that later versions think of implementing such features...

Or implement it and suggest to them.

Comment: I would definitely consider implementing it myself or at the very least suggesting it to the maintainers, but first I wanted to make sure that there wasn't an existing (or better) way to do this that's out there already!

Comment: Ok! Sorry... I apologize these hard words of mine

Comment: No problem! Not harsh words and quite reasonable. If no one comes up with anything then I'll post it to the Grunt team directly.